# numpy find two dimensional array within another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is the simplest of questions but I couldn't find an answer after searching for an hour and half. Almost all of the solutions I found is in 1D. My first array is very large, over two million entries, in two dimensions. I also created another 2D array(10,10) filled with zeroes. I'm trying to locate this second zero array within the first one.

Comment: The problem isn't as simple as you think.  The values matching your 10x10 array will not be in one place in the big array.  They will be in 10 separate blocks of 10, separated by 1000s of other values.  No one has implemented a fast 2d equivalent of `in1d`.